# Getting a sublist using regex

Tags: kdb

I have a list as such:

```
myList: ("ab";"bc";"cd","de");
```

I would like to get a sublist like that contains "b"
I know i can do this:

```
myList like "*b*"
```

However this returns a binary list. 1100b;
How can I return a list of ("ab";"bc") instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code returns needed sublist

```
myList: ("ab";"bc";"cd","de");
myList where myList like "*b*"
```

As you have mentioned

1. `myList like "*b*"` returns boolean list `1100`
2. `where 1100` returns list of indices with true value: `0, 1`
3. `myList 0 1` returns first two elements of `myList`